Is it possible to prevent usb udev automount from the boot partition on raspberry pi os (i.e. cmdline.txt, firstrun.sh etc)
I would like to prevent an SSD drive from being automounted prior to first boot. I.e. by perhaps running something from cmdline.txt or firstun.sh.
I'm happy for it to either prevent mounting of a specific drive, or all drives, or add rules for udev.
Just from the boot partition of an otherwise stock raspberry pi OS image.
Thanks

Have you tried removing the drive from /etc/fstab?
